# Exception: You do not have permission to call insertRowsAfter (line 5)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a custom function that inserts a row after a certain point. When I created a working version of what I intend for my function to do, my function shows an exception "Exception: You do not have permission to call insertRowsAfter (line 5)." despite the function working when I run it.

```
function CREATEROW() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

sheet.insertRowsAfter(10, 1);
}
```

So why is it screaming at me?

Comment: From `I'm making a custom function that inserts a row`, at the custom function, unfortunately, there are not all methods for Google Apps Script. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services) I think that the reason of your issue is due to this. Although there is the workaround for achieving this [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/Enhanced-Custom-Function-for-Google-Spreadsheet-using-Web-Apps-as-Wrapper), I thought that in your situation, the custom menu, button and so on instead of the custom function might be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

A custom function cannot affect cells other than those it returns a value to. In other words, a custom function cannot edit arbitrary cells, only the cells it is called from and their adjacent cells. To edit arbitrary cells, use a custom menu to run a function instead.

Reference: [Custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)